# ASP.Net Calendar/Events application

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm wondering if there are any free calendar/event tracking applications for asp.net out there. I want to be able to plug something into my existing website that will let an admin log in and add events to a calendar. Users can then see a short list of links of upcoming events on the front-page which they could then click to see more details. Is there anything out there like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be [VCalendar](http://www.scripts.com/asp-scripts/calendar-scripts/vcalendar-an-open-source-web-calendar/).  I've not used it but looking at it looks like a solid calendar application that I would use.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely start by looking at [DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/). It has a free "light" version if you just want a nice (but read-only) Outlook-like schedule component, but the pay version is much more full-featured.